# Proof of linear independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am looking for insight onto this theorem I will post. I will also post what I have for a potential proof, but I don't think it is very rigours. I am looking for one that maybe uses induction better, or is easier to follow etc.

$\mathbf{Thereom}:$ Suppose $v_1,v_2,…,v_n$ are non zero eigevectors of a matrix A belonging to distinct eigen values $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,…,\lambda_n$ . Then $v_1,v_2,..,v_2$ are linearly independent.

$\mathbf{Proof}: $

Suppose; (1)$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+…+a_nv_n=0 $$

$$(1) \times A= a_1Av_1+a_2Av_2+…+a_nAv_n=0$$

(2)$$0=a_1\lambda_1v_1+a_2\lambda_2v_2+…+a_n\lambda_nv_n$$

(3)$$(1) \times \lambda_n= a_1\lambda_nv_1+…+a_n\lambda_nv_n=0$$

(4)$$(2-3) \rightarrow a_1(\lambda_1-\lambda_n)v_1+…+a_n(\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_{n})v_{n-1}=0$$

Then Iam thinking something along lines of $(4) \times A$ and $(4) \times \lambda_{n-1}$ and continuing this type of argument and taking not that since the eigenvalues are distinct $\lambda_i-\lambda_j \ne 0$ and eigenvectors $\ne 
0$

However, it seems to messy and I think there must be a better proof. Please let me know what you all think , thanks.

Comment: You're very nearly there.  Just start by assuming that you have a minimal linear combination (i.e. using the smallest number of vectors possible).  Then when you are able to remove $v_{n}$ you have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current proof works fine. You will in the end reach something like
$$a_1(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)(\lambda_1 - \lambda_3) \cdots (\lambda_1 - \lambda_n) v_1 = 0$$
which implies $v_1 = 0$, a contradiction.

In fact, the case of two eigenvectors is easy to prove, so you might stop one step earlier in your proof, but maybe it would not be as elegant.

You can add a little more compactness to the proof by starting with the equation:
$$0 = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n$$
Then applying:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= (A - \lambda_nI)0 = (A - \lambda_nI)(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n) \\
&= (A-\lambda_n)a_1v_1 + \dots + (A - \lambda_n)a_nv_n \\
&= a_1(\lambda_1 - \lambda_n) v_1 + \dots + a_1 \underbrace{(\lambda_n - \lambda_n)}_{=0}v_n
\end{align}$$
which avoids the hassle of having two equations and subtracting them.